# Mostrar información de la selección en un <select> <option>

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

buen día!
Tengo este `select option` donde la información que muestra es a partir de un procedimiento almacenado.

```
<select id="selectTitle" class="form-control" name="tipoApp" data-init-plugin="select2" required>
  <option value=" ">LANZAMIENTOS</option>
  @foreach (var x in ViewBag.titulos)
  { 
    <option value="@x.TIT_LANZ">@x.TIT_LANZ</option>
  }
 </select>
```

Con esto me muestra los títulos que tengo almacenados en la base de datos.
Y este seria mi procedimiento almacenado que uso para buscar dichos títulos.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [LANDINGPAGE].[SELECT_LANZAMIENTO]
  @P_PAIS VARCHAR(200)
AS
    select NUMB_ID_DASHBOARD AS ID_DASH,
       TITULO_LANZAMIENTO AS TIT_LANZ,
       PAIS as PAIS
    FROM LANDINGPAGE.PORTAL
    where NUMB_ESTATUS = 1 AND PAIS = @P_PAIS
```

Lo que busco es que cuando seleccione un título de lanzamiento me muestre la información que corresponde a dicho título, por ejemplo seleccione una opción y esto es lo que contiene.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradeceria.

Comment: generar un evento después que seleccione el titulo, ¿esa es tu consulta? o es que entendi mal

Comment: y me podrías dar un ejemplo por favor, es que soy nueva en esto :)

Comment: en tu grafico donde quedaria el combo

Comment: Qudaria arribita de donde dice Banners pertenecientes

Answer (score 1):

primero, hay 2 formas, creando un view que muestre la información de la opción seleccionada, y la otra usando ajax. usando la primera harias los siguiente

En el evento `Change` del select, le pones que te re-direccione a al view con la info, así digamos.

```
$('#selectTitle').change(function(event){
    document.location.href='/listarproductos?id='+$(this).val();
})
```

y en la página de destino obtienes las [variables por la URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003953/asp-net-mvc-extract-parameter-of-an-url) y los listas en ese view.

Y la otra creando un método en el controlador, que te retorne la información adicional, ejemplo.

**Controlador**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ObtenerListadoObjetosJSTree(int id)
    {
        List<productos> productos = metodoquetedevuelveunalistadeproductos(id);
        return Json(productos);
    }
```

**OnChangeSelect**

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectTitle').change(function(){
        ObtenerProductos($(this).val());
    })
});
```

**Ajax**

```
function ObtenerProductos(ID) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'Productos/listarproductos',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({id: ID}),
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#divespera').html('espere...');
    }
}).done(function (data, result) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (ort, rt, qrt) {
    console.log(ort);
    console.log(rt);
    console.log(qrt);
});
}
```

Obviamente el ajax tienes que ponerlo en una hoja de Javascript e importar las librerias de JQuery, aunque como estas usando Boostrap, ya debes haberla importado.

Suerte.

Comment: y si por ejemplo los datos que quiero mostrar los saco de aquí seria igual?
[http://imgur.com/a/RI4dY]

Comment: No, ya que estas consultando a otro dominio, fuera de tu projecto (CrossDomain) y en IE11 (y versiones postteriores) te funcionaria, pero para firefox, chrome y otros no, ya que te bloquean ese tipo de llamadaos por seguirdad, aunque usando llamadas del tipo [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery) si se puede

Comment: oh ya, aamm y con esto a que te refieres `List<productos> productos = metodoquetedevuelveunalistadeproductos(id);`

Comment: `metodoquetedevuelveunalistadeproductos(id)` es un método que tu programaras en cual te devolvera una lista de productos con el ID que le mandes, ya sea sacan dolos de una base de datos, un XML, etc. esa es parte de tu lógica.

Comment: seria mucho abusar de ti pero no me podrías ayudar?
A veces no se como plantear las cosas bien :/

Comment: Este sitio está hecho para ayudar, así que dime en que mas puedo ayudarte.

Comment: o me podrías como orientar con respecto a ese método?

Comment: Que tipo de conexion a datos estas usando? Entity framework, SQL, Servicios Web?

Comment: con Sql server.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59502/discussion-between-gabriel-jeremy-rodriguez-river-and-amairani-fernanda).